# Adding an Observable List to a Table in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am still new to working in the JavaFX Environment and I am trying to make an MVC management system application. I'm currently not receiving any issues when running my application, however the table isn't populating with any of the objects from the array list. Is the issue with how I am calling the getCurrentList()? Apologies if this is obvious, but any help is appreciated.

**FacultyController.java**

```
import au.edu.uts.ap.javafx.*;

import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import model.Student;
import javafx.beans.property.*;


public class FacultyController extends Controller<FacultyController> {

    
    public ObservableList<model.Student> studentsL;
    
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;    
    
   @FXML
    private TableView<model.Student> studentTable;
   
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<model.Student, String> name;
   
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<model.Student, String> email;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<model.Student, String> phone;


//Read Student List into Table
@FXML private void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resources){

    model.Students studentList = new model.Students();
    studentsL.equals(studentList.getCurrentList());
 
 
    
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model.Student, String>("name"));
    email.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model.Student, String>("email")); 
    phone.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model.Student, String>("phone"));

    studentTable.setItems(studentsL);
   
}
```

**Faculty.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="center" prefHeight="433.0" prefWidth="673.0" spacing="10" styleClass="background" stylesheets="@tmsfx.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.FacultyController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="116.0" prefWidth="650.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="23.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="126.0" style="-fx-text-fill: white; -fx-font-size: 32;" stylesheets="@tmsfx.css" text="Filters" textFill="WHITE" />
            <Label layoutX="38.0" layoutY="69.0" style="-fx-font-size: 14; -fx-text-fill: white;" text="Name:" />
            <TextField layoutX="102.0" layoutY="66.0" />
            <Label layoutX="288.0" layoutY="70.0" style="-fx-text-fill: white; -fx-font-size: 14px;" text="Email:" />
            <TextField layoutX="350.0" layoutY="67.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="253.0" prefWidth="572.0" stylesheets="@tmsfx.css">
         <children>
            <Separator layoutX="15.0" layoutY="13.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="617.0" />
            <TableView fx:id="studentTable" items="${controller.student.students}" layoutX="18.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="617.0" stylesheets="@tmsfx.css">
                <placeholder><Label text="Student list is not listed" /></placeholder>
              <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="name" prefWidth="173.0" text="Name">
                    <cellValueFactory> <PropertyValueFactory property="Name" /></cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn fx:id="email" prefWidth="215.0" text="Email"> 
                    <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="Email" /></cellValueFactory> 
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn fx:id="phone" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="176.0" text="Phone"> 
              <cellValueFactory> <PropertyValueFactory property="phone" /></cellValueFactory> 
                </TableColumn>
              </columns>
            </TableView>
            <Separator layoutX="10.0" layoutY="231.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="625.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="580.0">
         <children>
            <Button alignment="TOP_CENTER" cancelButton="true" layoutX="3.0" layoutY="1.0" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToAdd" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="60.0" style="-fx-pref-width: 100px; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-effect: dropshadow;" stylesheets="@tmsfx.css" text="Add">
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect></Button>
            <Button disable="true" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="1.0" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="Delete">
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect></Button>
            <Button disable="true" layoutX="213.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Select">
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect></Button>
            <Button disable="true" layoutX="317.0" layoutY="1.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-effect: dropshadow;" stylesheets="@tmsfx.css" text="SLIP">
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect></Button>
            <Button layoutX="422.0" layoutY="1.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="90.0" onAction="#switchToTMS" style="-fx-effect: dropshadow;" text="Report">
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect></Button>
            <Button layoutX="527.0" layoutY="1.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToMenu" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="90.0" style="-fx-effect: dropshadow;" text="Close">
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**Student.java**

```
package model;


import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Student {
    private StringProperty name;
    private StringProperty email;
    private StringProperty phone;
    private StringProperty address;
    private StringProperty ID;
    private StringProperty type; 
    private IntegerProperty credits;
    private DoubleProperty payPerCredit;
    private DoubleProperty totalFee;
    private DoubleProperty scholarship;
    private DoubleProperty netFee;
    private DoubleProperty deduction;
    private DoubleProperty deductionRate;
    private Faculty faculty;

    public Student(String name, String email, String phone, String address, String ID, String type, int credits, double scholarship, String deductionCode) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.name.set(name);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.email.set(email);
        this.phone = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.phone.set(phone);
        this.address = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.address.set(address);
        this.ID = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.ID.set(ID);
        this.type = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.type.set(type);
        this.credits = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        this.credits.set(credits);
        this.payPerCredit = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        this.payPerCredit.set(500.00);     
        this.totalFee = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        this.totalFee.bind(this.credits.multiply(this.payPerCredit));
        this.scholarship = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        this.scholarship.set(scholarship);
        this.deductionRate = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        this.deductionRate.set(0.10);
        this.deduction = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        if (deductionCode.equals("2022AUT"))
        this.deduction.bind(this.totalFee.multiply(this.deductionRate));
        else 
        this.deduction.set(0.00);
        this.netFee = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        this.netFee.bind(this.totalFee.subtract(deduction).subtract(scholarship));
        
    }

    public void updateDetails(String name, String email, String phone, String address, String ID, String type, int credits, double scholarship, String deductionCode){       
        this.name.set(name);    
        this.email.set(email);        
        this.phone.set(phone);     
        this.address.set(address);        
        this.ID.set(ID);    
        this.type.set(type);
        this.credits.set(credits);        
        this.scholarship.set(scholarship);
        if (deductionCode.equals("2022AUT"))
            this.deduction.bind(this.totalFee.multiply(this.deductionRate));
        else 
            this.deduction.set(0.00);
    }
    
    public void setFaculty(Faculty e){
        this.faculty = e;
    }
    
    public Faculty getFaculty(){
        return this.faculty;
    }
    
    public ReadOnlyStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name.getValue();
    }
    
    public ReadOnlyStringProperty emailProperty() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email.getValue();
    }
    
    public ReadOnlyStringProperty phoneProperty() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getPhone(){
        return phone.getValue();
    }
    
    public ReadOnlyStringProperty addressProperty() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address.getValue();
    }
    
    public ReadOnlyStringProperty IDProperty() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getID(){
        return ID.getValue();
    }
    
    public ReadOnlyStringProperty typeProperty() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type.getValue();
    }
    
    public IntegerProperty creditsProperty() {
        return credits;
    }
    
    public int getCredits(){
        return credits.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty payPerCreditProperty() {
        return payPerCredit;
    }    
    
    public double getPayPerCredit(){
        return payPerCredit.get();
    }
    
    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty totalFeeProperty() {
        return totalFee;
    }    
    
    public double getTotalFee(){
        return totalFee.get();
    }
    
    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty netFeeProperty() {
        return netFee;
    }    
    
    public double getNetFee(){
        return netFee.get();
    }
    
    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty scholarshipProperty() {
        return scholarship;
    }    
    
    public double getScholarship(){
        return scholarship.get();
    }
    
    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty deductionProperty() {
        return deduction;
    }    
    
    public double getDeduction(){
        return deduction.get();
    }
    
    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty deductionRateProperty() {
        return deductionRate;
    }    
    
    public double getDeductionRate(){
        return deductionRate.get();
    }
    
    public boolean hasName(String name){
        return getName().toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase().trim());
    } 
    
    public boolean hasEmail(String email){
        return getEmail().toLowerCase().contains(email.toLowerCase().trim());
    }

    public boolean deleteStudent() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

**Students.java**

```
package model;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Students {

    private ObservableList<Student> students;
    private ObservableList<Student> current;

    public Students() {
        current = FXCollections.<Student>observableArrayList();
        students = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Student("Thomas Muller", "thomas.muller@uts.com", "99991111", "3 Byern St. Sydney 2001", "13697480", "Full-Time", 48, 4000, ""),
                new Student("Alice Stefan", "alice.stefan@uts.com", "88881111", "24 Pitt St. Sydney 2001", "14517880", "Part-Time", 24,0, ""),
                new Student("Lucy Lu", "lucy.lu@uts.com", "98981100", "11 Hunter St. Sydney 2100", "13267102", "Full-Time", 48,0, "2022AUT"),
                new Student("Andreas Brehme", "andreas.b@uts.com", "90001222", "91 Sussex St. Sydney 2100", "13678020", "Full-Time", 48,0, ""),
                new Student("Ruddy Voller", "ruddy.v@uts.com", "98980000", "15 Stan St. Sydney 2100", "13972870", "Full-Time", 48,8000, ""),
                new Student("Monica Shwarz", "monica.s@uts.com", "92241188", "155 Jones St. Sydney 2001", "13859610", "Part-Time", 24,0, "2022AUT")
        );
        current.addAll(students);
        students.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Student>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Student> c) {
                current.clear();
                current.addAll(students);
            }
        });
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
    }

    public void addStudent(String name, String email, String phone, String address, String ID, String type, int credits, double scholarship, String deductionCode) {
        students.add(new Student(name,email,phone,address,ID,type,credits,scholarship, deductionCode));
    }
    
    public boolean hasStudent(String name) {
        for(Student e:students)
            if(e.hasName(name)&& !name.isEmpty())
                return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    public Student getStudent(String name){
        for(Student p: students)
            if(p.hasName(name))
                return p;
        return null;                        
    }

    public void remove(Student p) {
        this.students.remove(p);
    }

    public void remove(List<Student> selectedItems) {
        this.students.removeAll(selectedItems);
    }

    public void addStudents(List<Student> selectedItems) {
        this.students.addAll(selectedItems);
    }

    public ObservableList<Student> getCurrentList() {
        return this.current;
    }

    public void filterList(String name, String email) {

        List<Student> temp = new ArrayList<>();

        students.forEach((Student p) -> {
            try {
                if ((p.hasName(name)) || (p.hasEmail(email))) {
                    temp.add(p);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        });

        this.current.clear();
        this.current.addAll(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have so much noise in your code. That makes your code hard to follow. First, make sure your list has objects using `System.out`. Next,  model your code based on a good tutorial. `Student` looks terrible and is hard to follow. I am not even sure of the purpose of `Students`. Wow! It looks like you created it to what a list already does. What is the logic behind that? I have never used the read-only properties, so I could be wrong, but it does not make sense to me to have a read-only property with a set method.

Comment: For an example of integrating a TableView with an FXML controller, see the [makery tutorial](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part2/)

Comment: asking for debugging help _requires_ a [mcve] .. mind the __M__!

Comment: as is, the question is far too broad (due to too many errors/misconceptions/unusual patterns) - focus on one problem, do some research on it, apply to your requirement, when stuck come back with a runnable example demonstrating what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your data model is `Students` and the students you want to display are stored in `current`.
If that's correct you have to set this list to your table's items.

```
studentTable.setItems(studentList.getCurrentList());
```

instead of

```
studentTable.setItems(studentsL);
```

Note: I don't see any initialization of `studentsL` so I would expect a `NullPointerException` at this line: `studentsL.equals(studentList.getCurrentList());` (which does nothing because you don't store the result)

EDIT

This minimal `Application` works fine.
Maybe there's something wrong with your FXML usage.
I don't use FXML so I have no further idea :(

```
public final class FacultyController extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Students model = new Students();
        TableColumn<Student, String> id = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        // id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        id.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> cdf.getValue().idProperty());
        TableView<Student> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(id);
        table.setItems(model.getCurrentList());
        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Comment: I've made the changes so `studentTable.setItems(studentList.getCurrentList());` I've also made the changes I also in the fxml made the `items={$controller.students.current}`. Unfortunately the outcome is still the same

Comment: @Tarrmu I don't think that `items={$controller.students.current}` is a valid thing to write in FXML (I could be wrong, I didn't test it). I advise just setting the items in code rather than in FXML, usually in the initialize method as was advised in this answer.  I don't advise trying to set the items both in FXML and in code.

Comment: @Tarrmu I don't use FXML but create the nodes in code. I wrote a minimal `Application` with your `Student` and `Students` and it works fine (see EDIT in answer)

Comment: the data class exposes _properties_ .. use them in the valueFactories

Comment: @kleopatra did I get your intension correctly in `setCellValueFactory`?